# Charging with multiple vanguard weapons

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

I am building an charging character, and I have a question about the spiked shield enchanted with the [vanguard weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=2965).

What if I charge while holding the spiked shield (off-hand) but use a different weapon (main hand), will I still get the +1d8 on a charge?

And what if I have a 2nd vanguard weapon, will I get the 1d8 twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

This is bonus damage, and two bonuses from the same named gamed element don't stack. More importantly though, there is a little known clause in the first adventurer's vault that says you can't use the second vanguard weapon on the charge:

> Many weapons have properties that provide a constant benefit. To gain the benefit of a weapon’s property, you must be wielding the weapon. **Unless specified otherwise, a property affects only the weapon to which it’s attached.** For example, a +2 cunning dagger, which bestows a –2 penalty to an enemy’s saving throws against your weapon powers, affects only powers that are delivered using that weapon. You couldn’t hold the weapon in your off-hand and gain the benefit of the property on powers delivered using a main weapon. (AV 56, Emphasis mine)

I've expounded a lot more on this particular sentence in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35715/1084). But that's neither here nor there really, the two wouldn't stack even without that as they are the same game identified source.