# Definition of "using" in Dizzying Mace

Tags: dnd-4e

> Benefit: When you hit an enemy with a power that dazes the target while you are using a mace, the target also takes a penalty to attack rolls equal to your Constitution modifier for as long as it remains dazed by your attack.

Obviously this works with weapon attacks with a mace, or with implement attacks if you have a way to do it (Ironscar Rod, Unforgettable Cudgel, or Crusader's Weapon for example).

However, what does "use" mean here?  If, for example, you are wielding a mace, and hit an enemy with a power that dazes that doesn't have the weapon/implement keyword, are you "using" it?  Does "using" require you to be "using" it on that attack?

Example:

You hit an enemy with Dragonfear, which does not have a weapon or implement keyword.  You are holding a mace.  You also have the following feat:

> Dragon's Terror.  Benefit: One creature you hit with dragonfear is also dazed until the end of your next turn.

Are they Dazed and -2 to hit (from Dragonfear)?  Or Dazed, -2 to hit from Dragonfear, and -CON to hit from Dizzying Mace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Since the power does not have have the weapon or implement keyword it does not qualify as having "used" the mace in this case.

See [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35715/1084) answer for the details. I think this particular property is a bit more clear than the Vanguard Weapons, but the same thing applies. You have to actually use the weapon to make a weapon or implement attack for the property to trigger.